# How to show destination address in InfoPanel using package flutter_mapbox_navigation

Tags: flutter, dart

I have implemented flutter_mapbox_navigation package and I am wondering if I can achieve something like the attached picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/15IKC.png

Below is the implementation code

```
directions = MapBoxNavigation();

                      directions
                          .registerRouteEventListener(_onRouteEvent);
                      _options = MapBoxOptions(
                          zoom: 18.0,
                          simulateRoute: true,
                          voiceInstructionsEnabled: true,
                          bannerInstructionsEnabled: true,
                          mode: MapBoxNavigationMode.drivingWithTraffic,
                          isOptimized: true,
                          mapStyleUrlDay:
                              'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v12',
                          mapStyleUrlNight:
                              'mapbox://styles/mapbox/outdoors-v12',
                          units: VoiceUnits.metric,
                          language: "en");

                      WayPoint sourceWaypoint = WayPoint(
                          name: startPlace!.placeName,
                          latitude:
                              startPlace!.geometry!.coordinates![1],
                          longitude:
                              startPlace!.geometry!.coordinates![0]);
                      WayPoint destinationWaypoint = WayPoint(
                          name: endPlace!.placeName,
                          latitude: endPlace!.geometry!.coordinates![1],
                          longitude:
                              endPlace!.geometry!.coordinates![0]);
                      var wayPoints = <WayPoint>[];
                      wayPoints.add(sourceWaypoint);
                      wayPoints.add(destinationWaypoint);

                      await directions.startNavigation(
                          wayPoints: wayPoints, options: _options);
```